# Contact form 7 Submit Button’s Click Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

How to use contact form 7 submit button’s click function to change a given text in Text Area from Upper Case to Lower Case letters? – Please Help

Comment: share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Paste your code here too.

Comment: Better change it on the server-side (PHP) not via Javascript. Or if you change it via Javascript, do it as well and already while the user is typing in so that this is more transparent.